# scope variable of the controller is not recognized in nested directives

Tags: angularjs

I have created two directives and inserted the first directive into the second one. The content of template attribute works fine but the scope variable of the controller is not recognized. Please provide me solution on this

sample link: http://jsbin.com/zugeginihe/2/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide the attribute for the second directive.

**HTML**

```
<div second-dir first-dir-scope="content">

  <div first-dir first-dir-scope="content"></div>

</div>
```

Link demo: http://jsbin.com/jotagiwolu/2/edit

Comment: thanks a lot. is there any other way which can be done in the js file rather than view

Comment: You can get the content value by using "console.log(scope.$parent.content);". But it is a bad idea!

Comment: shall we use require: "^firstDir" in the second directive?

Comment: @user1153484   Yes you can do this, and it would be better way

Answer (score 1):

The best option would using parent directive, We could take use of `require` option of directive like `require: '?secondDir'` in `firstDir`

**Code**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.content = "test1";
});

myApp.directive("firstDir", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        require: '?secondDir',
        scope: {
            firstDirScope: "="
        },
        template: "<div>first content</div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, secondDir) {
            console.log(scope.firstDirScope, 'first');
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive("secondDir", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        scope: {
            firstDirScope: "="
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.firstDirScope, 'second');
        }
    };
});
```

[**Working JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/tenewupora/1/edit?html,js,output)